# how to send an alert message with Turkish characters

Tags: jsf, character-encoding

I am programming a Web-Application with Java EE and JSF.

I want to give alert (javascript) messages with Turkish characters (such as Ç,ü and ö etc.) on my app. But, after alert function is fired, I see the alert message with unrelated characters such as `<?>`, instead of Turkish characters on .xhtml pages on any browser (I tried it on IE10 and Chrome).

I need an advice to handle the problem. If I find a solution, I can also use this to set values of element (ex./h:commandButton) by javascript.

**EDIT:**

**Additional information** - Static strings that includes Turkish letters on html or jsf tags are shown properly. However, when I change them via some javascript functions, if there is any Turkish characters in strings that are changed, these Turkish letters cannot be shown properly.

Comment: Only on Chrome? You tried with Firefox, IE, Opera, whatever and there you did not have any issues?

Comment: use the meta tag `<meta encoding="utf8">` in the head of your html document

Comment: @Apolo, I use <meta encoding="utf8" /> in h:head, but nothing is changed.

Comment: `Turkish Characters` is supported by `utf8`.You can define utf8 format  in the head of HTML page. If you defined `utf8` format in Html page,but your problem is continuing,then check the Chrome settings. [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=tr)

Comment: @Gimby, I tried on IE, but I got the same result.

Comment: Exactly, so the "in Chrome" bit is a red herring and very misleading;  would remove that and simply say that you get junk when the page is rendered in a browser. As others are suspecting, you most likely simply have a lack of proper page encoding.

Comment: @Gimby, I edit the part we talked about.

Comment: The exact answer depends on how exactly you're rendering the alert messages. This question can only be answered with a proper [mcve] which fully demonstrates the exact use case with a code snippet as minimal as possible. There are many possible causes for this, but they indeed all boil down to that the character encoding is wrong. How exacty to properly set the character encoding in turn thus depends on the exact use case, which is completely lacking in the question.

Comment: And, please ignore the `<meta encoding="utf8">` advice in a previous comment. It has only potential effect when the HTML page is opened via `file://` instead of `http://`, or is embedded in an external resource such as an e-mail. Of course you're not doing that as opening a HTML page that way wouldn't execute the JSF framework at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is too old question but I want to answer for maybe someone need.

If your problem with alert messages, open your javascript file on notepad and save as with Utf-8 options.

Or you can use same technic for others js file you need encoding char.

Answer (score -1):

If its just specific to chrome may be you could try changing the page encoding.

Got Control->Tools->Encoding and change that to Auto Detect or Unicode or turkish etc..

If its a general issue then add the meta info

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">

               or

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">
```

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script>
    function alertText() {
        alert(document.getElementById("turkish").innerHTML);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="turkish">Türkçe olarak hellow dünya</div>
    <input type="Button" onclick="alertText()" value="Say" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can also pass Content-Type and Content Language through a filter in jsp

Comment: @Syam S, when I use <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr" />, I get the error below; com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence. Anyway, I see some errors, before I run the app, in the.xhtml files on some words such as "Bölge0".

Comment: @Syam S, usage with <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr" /> also gives the same error.

Comment: can you share your html code. I could try it in my machine and fix it if possible.